# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'next'

Tags: python, methods, linked-list

I've been trying to make a LinkedList and it seemed to be working fine until I added a class where I can insert a node at a specific index.

When I try to run this line of code:

```
 print(my_list.node(0))
```

after having ran:

```
print(my_list.node(1))
my_list.insert(1, 3)
```

I receive the following error: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'next'`

which occurs in this code block on the second line

```
    def node(self, index):
    if index >= self.length() or index < 0:
        print("ERROR: 'Get' Index out of range!")
        return None
    cur_idx = 0
    cur_node = self.head
    while True:
        cur_node = cur_node.next
        if cur_idx == index:
            return cur_node.data
        cur_idx += 1
```

and seems to originate in this code block at the fourth line

```
def length(self):
    current = self.head
    total = 0
    while current.next is not None:
        total += 1
        current = current.next
    return total
```

This error has me confused as it doesn't occur until after I insert a node value and try to display the updated node, but trying to display any node has the same effect. Trying to display a list where it worked before inserting the node value provides a similar error as well: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'data'`

This error points back to the sixth line of this code block:

```
    def print(self):
    elements = []
    current_node = self.head
    while current_node.next is not None:
        current_node = current_node.next
        elements.append(current_node.data)
    print(elements)
```

I'm honestly not very sure what the resolution to this problem would be. I would imagine it has something to do with the insert method I had for inserting a node, but my IDE lists no errors there. Type hints and specifying the data type did not seem to fix the problem either. After running the debugger, it provides this error:

```
list_length.current_node = {NameError}name 'list_length' is not defined
```

I've attached the full code to the following pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/2NHiPJ6q

The only solutions to similar problems I found online seemed to be resolved by defining the class, but I'm pretty certain that isn't the problem here. I hope someone can help me out here!

Comment: Did you mean: `my_list.insert(1, Node(3))`?

Comment: @quamrana Oh my goodness, I cannot tell you how long I was looking at this and I didn't realize that. Thank you so much! This fixed my problem immediately.

Comment: I hope this experience will help you to learn debugging techniques. From your Error Traceback (thanks for including it, its amazing how many posters here just say 'I got an error') it was obvious to look for somewhere where an `int` had been inserted into the structure where a `Node` with a `data` attribute was expected.